# Legacy code: Code First one to one or zero relationship

Tags: entity-framework, code-first, legacy-code

I have following legacy code fragment that **I can't change**:

```
public class EntityA
{
  int SeqId { get; set; }  //Not part of the key

  [Association("EntityB", "Seq_ID", "Seq_ID")]
  public EntityB EntityB { get; set; }
}

public class EntityB
{
  [Key]
  int SeqId { get; set; }
}
```

Database was created via SQL and not with Entity Framework. There are no foreign
keys and the relation is handled as one to one/zero.

Now, we must use the model for code first and Entity Framework adds a foreign key relation.
Since I can't change the model, but I can override the *OnModelCreating* event, I want to
rewrite the relationship from required to optional. I was trying to add

```
modelBuilder.Entity<EntityA>().Property(i => i.EntityB).IsOptional();
```

and

```
modelBuilder.Entity<EntityA>().HasOptional(i => i.EntityB).WithOptionalDependent()
```

but in both cases Entity Framework complains.

Comment: What's the exception? Is `Seq_ID` nullable in the database?

Comment: The Exception I get:
_Multiplicity conflicts with the referential constraint in Role 'EntityA_EntityB_Target' in relationship 'EntityA_EntityB'. 
  Because all of the properties in the Dependent Role are non-nullable, multiplicity of the Principal Role must be '1'._

Seq_ID is not nullable and sadly I can't change it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We used following workaround:

delete the foreign key directly after creating the model. Not beautiful but effective.